# Symbian UIQ

Tags: uiq3

I am new in Symbian UIQ. So anyone can help me out about following queries.

What is Symbian UIQ?
which SDK are used for developing application using Symbian UIQ?
Can we call webservice through this application or can we use Webservice in that?
GPS facility are available in Symbian UIQ.
and last thing can we use third party application through, this application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you start at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIQ) for a basic overview.

UIQ (User Interface Quartz) is a framework (mostly) for the Userinterface as the name says, like [S60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S60_platform) or [QT](http://pepper.troll.no/s60prereleases/).

Before you start to invest to much work in UIQ, it's woth to mention:

> ...UIQ will cease to exist. S60 is the UI choice of Symbian Foundation; UIQ will contribute its assets to the foundation